# Inter-program communication for an arbitrary number of programs

Tags: c, linux, concurrency

I am attempting to have a bunch of independent programs intelligently allocate shared resources among themselves. However, I could have only one program running, or could have a whole bunch of them.

My thought was to `mmap` a virtual file in each program, but the concurrency is killing me. Mutexes are obviously ineffective because each program could have a lock on the file and be completely oblivious of the others. However, my attempts to write a semaphore have all failed, since the semaphore would be internal to the file, and I can't rely on only one thing writing to it at a time, etc.

I've seen quite a bit about named pipes but it doesn't seem to be to be a practical solution for what I'm doing since I don't know how many other programs there will be, if any, nor any way of identifying which program is participating in my resource-sharing operation.

Comment: Which operating system? (Sounds like some flavor of Linux?)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am working on a Linux box.

Comment: Will you have a master process that can delegate resources to worker processes? Or will the processes need to negotiate which resources will belong to which processes? Which APIs have you investigated and found insufficient for your problem?

Comment: pthread mutexes and cvars can be used on a mmap'd segment if you apply the appropriate pshared attributes.

Comment: @sarnold: I will not have a master process, just a bunch of them that need to play nicely together. I haven't seen any lightweight APIs that do what I'm trying to do without the creation of additional threads. If you know of any, I'm certainly willing to take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a UNIX-domain socket (`AF_UNIX`) - see [`man 7 unix`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html).

When a process starts up, it tries to `bind()` a well-known path.  If the `bind()` succeeds then it knows that it is the first to start up, and becomes the "resource allocator".  If the `bind()` fails with `EADDRINUSE` then another process is already running, and it can `connect()` to it instead.

You could also use a dedicated resource allocator process that always listens on the path, and arbitrates resource requests.

Comment: Reading through the man page, it looks like you can have only two processes connected to each socket. Is this correct?

Comment: @Andy Shulman: It works just like a network socket - if you're using `SOCK_STREAM`, then `accept()` returns a new one-to-one socket for each client that connects to the listening socket.  If you use `SOCK_DGRAM`, then you can receive messages from any number of processes on the same socket.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but personally my first thought would be to use [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) ([more detail](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/IntroductionToDBus)).  Should be easy enough within that framework for your processes/programs to register/announce themselves and enumerate/signal other registered processes, and/or to create a central resource arbiter and communicate with it.  Readily available on any system with gnome or KDE installed too.